# Accessing a server running on an android phone from outside

Tags: android, connection

I want to let the users browse and download their content on an android device through an internet connection.

I have successfully made a tiny HTTP server that works fine when you are on the local WIFI.

But the server cannot be reached from an outside network or when the phone is on 3G since the operator does not allow incoming connections.

The solution as I see is to let the phone make a outgoing connection to a proxy server and let the users connect to their phone through this proxy connection.

Is there an easy way to make this setup? Like a configuration in apache? I think I am looking for a reverse proxy where the server makes the initial connection to the proxy but I am not sure what the correct term is. Any hints or links to some documentation would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, since I got no answer from SO I implemented my own solution. It looks a lot like what is on this diagram: http://www.me.lv/jp/manual.html